# Payola: Stripe token can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, payola

I go to subscriptions/new, put my CC info and I get this:

[image]

No background worker installed. No turbolinks. What's wrong?

**Subscription_controller.rb**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  # bring in the `render_payola_status` helper.
  include Payola::StatusBehavior

  def new
    @plan = SubscriptionPlan.first
  end

  def create
    # do any required setup here, including finding or creating the owner object
    owner = current_user # this is just an example for Devise

    # set your plan in the params hash
    params[:plan] = SubscriptionPlan.find_by(id: 1)
    params[:stripeEmail] = owner.email

    # call Payola::CreateSubscription
    subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)



    # Render the status json that Payola's javascript expects
    render_payola_status(subscription)
  end
end
```

**views/subscriptions/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'payola/transactions/stripe_header' %>

<%= form_tag('/subscriptions',
      class: 'payola-onestep-subscription-form',
      'data-payola-base-path' => '/payola',
      'data-payola-error-selector' => '.payola-error',
      'data-payola-plan-type' => @plan.class,
      'data-payola-plan-id' => @plan.id
  ) do |f| %>
  <span class="payola-payment-error"></span>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="stripeEmail" data-payola="email"></input><br>
  Card Number<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="number"></input><br>
  Exp Month<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_month"></input><br>
  Exp Year<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="exp_year"></input><br>
  CVC<br>
  <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc"></input><br>
  <input type="submit"></input>

   <div class="alert alert-warning payola-error" style="display: none"></div>
<% end %>
```

**subscription Plan.rb (Model)**

```
class SubscriptionPlan < ActiveRecord::Base


    def redirect_path(subscription)
    # you can return any path here, possibly referencing the given subscription
    'http://google.com'
  end
end
```

Payola.configure do |config|

config.secret_key = 'sk_test_blablalblalblal'
  config.publishable_key = 'pk_test_rCxOKWqL22MjvOvc4RsutK6o'

config.send_email_for :receipt

config.default_currency = 'eur'
  # Example subscription:
  # 
  # config.subscribe 'payola.package.sale.finished' do |sale|
  #   EmailSender.send_an_email(sale.email)
  # end
  # 
  # In addition to any event that Stripe sends, you can subscribe
  # to the following special payola events:
  #
  #  - payola..sale.finished
  #  - payola..sale.refunded
  #  - payola..sale.failed
  #
  # These events consume a Payola::Sale, not a Stripe::Event
  #
  # Example charge verifier:
  #
  # config.charge_verifier = lambda do |sale|
  #   raise "Nope!" if sale.email.includes?('yahoo.com')
  # end

# Keep this subscription unless you want to disable refund handling
  config.subscribe 'charge.refunded' do |event|
    sale = Payola::Sale.find_by(stripe_id: event.data.object.id)
    sale.refund!
  end
end

Payola.background_worker = lambda do |klass, *args|
  klass.call(*args)
end